# JButton displaying differently in different PCs

Tags: java, swing

I am using Jbutton class to create a button in my application. This looks fine when I view it in my desktop. But, when I connect my pc from other computer (through remote desktop connection), a square background has been observed for that button. Attached are the buttons with different views. Please guide me in understanding the issue.

[View in my desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMpFL.png)
[View in remote desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kONvQ.png)

Comment: Welcome, Could you give more information, do you use a specific look and feels, what remote desktop are you using, ...

Comment: we use javax.swing.plaf.basic to set the look and fell preferences and we use mstsc(Windows) to connect to remote desktop

Comment: You should edit your question with helpful informations like those, the comments might be erase later.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that, in remote connection, your desktop set's UI to basic theme to reduce refresh rate and increase remote connection speed, you can maintain the cross-platform Look and feel using following tutorial:
[How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

You can use following code with your frame:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(lnfName);
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
frame.pack();
```

Replace `lnfName` with following line to  get system look and feel, which is not cross-platform  as:

```
UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()
```

To get Cross-platform look and feel, replace `lnfName` with following line:

```
UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName()
```

Which is nothing but Metal theme provided by Java.

Comment: I though about something like this but didn't have any source to post an answer. Could you find some ?